# Google Chrome on Ubuntu won't load some sites

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, google-chrome, internet

I just installed Ubuntu on an external hard drive, and everything is working perfectly. 
Only Chrome won't load some sites (Google, Facebook, or Twitter), however it can load every single other site.

I have a proxy server configured, but Firefox has no problem connecting to these sites. 
Given the fact that the google.com domain is not responsive on Chrome I can't send a bug report.

Anyone know of a fix?

Comment: what is the error you are getting when going to www.google.com in chrome?

Comment: It tries to load for a long time, then I receive a normal "no internet connection" error, although I have other sites running on the side. It is a normal "maybe a proxy?" error (Yes, I have a proxy, but as said all other sites work), I believe its https sites that won't load. Thanks

Comment: @JoColina It's not clear whether you've tried to load them without the proxy server being enabled (if this is an option). If you can disable, see if you can then load the website. If so, it's the proxy server. It's not clear whether you have control of the proxy server. If it looks like it's the proxy server's fault and you have access to it, see what the proxy's logs say.